# how to prevent check button to move when i drag the dialog in swt?

Tags: java, user-interface, swt, jface

When i create a check button and push button on both ends of the dialog in a buttons bar,
it is defaultly created well, but when i drag or resize the dialog, the check button moves away from the left end of the dialog. How should I prevent it from moving when i resize the dialog.
This is how i overrided my buttons bar.

```
       @Override
   protected void createButtonsForButtonBar(Composite parent) {
    super.createButtonsForButtonBar(parent);


    ((GridLayout) parent.getLayout()).numColumns = ((GridLayout) parent.getLayout()).numColumns+2;

    GridData checkData = new GridData(SWT.LEFT,
            SWT.BOTTOM,true,true);

    GridData labelData = new GridData(SWT.CENTER,
            SWT.CENTER,true,true);

    GridData closeLayoutData = new GridData(SWT.RIGHT,
            SWT.BOTTOM,true,true);

    parent.setLayoutData(closeLayoutData);

    Button close = getButton(IDialogConstants.CANCEL_ID);
    close.setText("Close");
    close.setLayoutData(closeLayoutData);
    close.setParent(parent);

    final Button checkButton = new Button(parent, SWT.CHECK);
    checkButton.setText("View All schedules");
    checkButton.setSelection(false);
    checkButton.setLayoutData(checkData);
    checkButton.setParent(parent);
    checkButton.moveAbove(close);
    checkButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            if (checkButton.getSelection()) {
                treeViewer.setFilters(new ViewerFilter[] { new ExistingExpiredScheduleFilter() });
            } else {
                treeViewer.setFilters(new ViewerFilter[] { new ExistingScheduleFilter() });
            }
        }
    });


    Label label = new Label(parent,SWT.HORIZONTAL);
    label.setLayoutData(labelData);
    label.setParent(parent);
    label.moveAbove(close);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
    protected void createButtonsForButtonBar(Composite parent)
    {
        final GridLayout layout = (GridLayout)parent.getLayout();
        layout.numColumns += 2;
        layout.makeColumnsEqualWidth = false;

        parent.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false));    

        final Button checkButton = new Button(parent, SWT.CHECK);
        checkButton.setText("View All schedules");
        checkButton.setSelection(false);
        checkButton.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, false, false));
        // Left out selection code for clarity

        final Label label = new Label(parent, SWT.NONE);
        label.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false));

        createButton(parent, IDialogConstants.OK_ID, IDialogConstants.OK_LABEL, true);

        createButton(parent, IDialogConstants.CANCEL_ID, "Close", false);
    }
```

There is no need to call `setParent`. I have created things in order so there is no need to reorder.

Comment: I'm wondering what mistake did i do?, i did all the same except setting the parent, does calling super method makes any difference and I've even tried without calling set parent. anyway your answer is correct

Comment: The super call just does the two `createButton` calls, I have done them in my code for clarity. The problem was mainly the layout data on `parent` which is normally right aligned. Also the 'grab horizontal space' parameters of the `GridData` values.